# Where did Mars live (what part of Rome)?

Tags: roman

I'm doing an important project on Mars.

Where did Mars live?

Comment: Given that Roman Gods are pretty much the Greek Gods with their names translated, the answer to where Mars lives is exactly where Ares lives, which is, for a good reason if you ever visit it, **Mount Olympus**.

Answer (score 4):

The first cult centre for Mars in Rome was the Altar of Mars on the [Campus Martius](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Gazetteer/Places/Europe/Italy/Lazio/Roma/Rome/_Texts/PLATOP*/Campus_Martius.html), or Field of Mars. The other main temple of Mars lay outside the city boundary, built to [fufill a vow](http://www.loebclassics.com/view/livy-history_rome_6/1924/pb_LCL172.213.xml) made during the war against the Gauls. 
[This link](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Gazetteer/Places/Europe/Italy/Lazio/Roma/Rome/_Texts/PLATOP*/Aedes_Martis.html) lists the main Roman temples of Mars.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

They lived on [Mount Olympus](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/742/967).

From answer linked.

> **[205]** *O magne **Olympi rector** et mundi arbiter,*
>   *Jam statue tandem gravibus aerumnis modum*
>
> [O mighty ruler of **Olympus**, judge of all the world,
>
>   set now at length a limit to our crushing cares, an end to our disasters.](http://www.theoi.com/Text/SenecaHerculesFurens.html)

That was from a play, in which it states that Olympus is where all of the Roman gods lived.

So Mars lived on Mount Olympus.